# Unable to upload file using angular file upload

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement `angular-file-upload` in my small application but did not get much success.

In my index.html, i have correctly added reference

```
<script src="/Scripts/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="FileUpload" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
</div>
```

**This is my controller code.**

```
//On select file
$scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
    $scope.selectedFile = null;
    if ($files.length > 0) {
            $scope.selectedFile = $files[0];
            $scope.attachment = {
                lastModified: $scope.selectedFile.lastModified,
                lastModifiedDate: $scope.selectedFile.lastModifiedDate,
                name: $scope.selectedFile.name,
                size: $scope.selectedFile.size,
                type: $scope.selectedFile.type,
                webkitRelativePath: $scope.selectedFile.webkitRelativePath
            };
    }
};
```

**Problem:**
When i browse and select file, this function is not being triggered/called and $files always remains null.

What i am missing here?

Comment: Have you included the module in your angular app config? E.g. `angular.module("YourApp", ["angularFileUpload"])`

Comment: Yes i added. But still the same case. Can you share an example tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple directives names angular-file-upload. can you please post link to the directive you are using?